# how can i solve this problem of coins from n shop in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

there is a problem that we have given n shops and each shop has 3 coins i.e GOLD ,PLATINUM,DIAMOND
customer has to get max of the coins 
conditions are as follows
he can only take at most 1 type of coin from 1 shop
for example

**INPUT**

i have a matrix
4 <--- no of shops
2  1  1 <-- max no of that we can have of gold,platinum,diamond 
5  4  5 <-- shop 1 have 5 gold coin,4 platinum and 5 diamond coin 
4  3  2 <-- for shop 2 
10 9  7 <-- for shop 3
8  2  9 <-- for shop 4

**OUTPUT**

answer is 27 
as we take gold coin from 1 and 3 shop and we take platinum coin from shop2
and we take diamond coin from shop 4
so SHOP 3 AND SHOP1=10+5
SHOP2=3
SHOP4=9
answer=10+5+3+9=27

Comment: Isn't that so-called *rucksack problem* (also known as *knapsack* problem)?

Comment: how can we relate it with KNAPSACK can you please explain

Comment: I do not know, input seems to be somewhat similar (limited *capacity* and items of various *values*), so I am simply asking (note ? at end of my previous comment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can just pick the coin which shop has the largest. So the key point is the order of pick. I think you can use [dfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to search all pick orders, and find the best one:

```
def pick_coins(demand, shops):
    # invalid input
    if sum(demand) > len(shops):
        return -1
    res = 0

    def dfs(demand, idx_remains, num):
        nonlocal res
        # all picked up
        if all(d == 0 for d in demand):
            # record it if it is max so far
            res = max(res, num)
            return

        for i, coin_num in enumerate(demand):
            if coin_num > 0:
                # which remain shop has max number of coin, and choose this one
                max_v, max_shop_idx = max((v[i], shop_idx) for shop_idx, v in enumerate(shops) if shop_idx in idx_remains)
                idx_remains.remove(max_shop_idx)
                demand[i] -= 1
                # do it recursively
                dfs(demand, idx_remains, num + max_v)
                # remember to revert the state when backtrack
                idx_remains.append(max_shop_idx)
                demand[i] += 1

    dfs(demand, list(range(len(shops))), 0)
    return res

def test():
    demand = [2, 1, 1]
    shops = [[5, 4, 5], [4, 3, 2], [10, 9, 7], [8, 2, 9]]
    print(pick_coins(demand, shops))    # output 27
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: can you explain it with terms of KNAPSACK

Comment: never heard about it before

Comment: max_v, max_shop_idx = max((v[i], shop_idx) for shop_idx, v in enumerate(shops) if shop_idx in idx_remains)    Can you please explain this line

Comment: I have a comment on it. `which remain shop has max number of coin, and choose this one`. For python grammar question, you can google it.

Comment: This solution will not work when idx_remains gets empty and also in a lot of cases.

Comment: @Akshay.N, could you please give me a counter-example? I have assumed `sum(demand) <= len(shops)` if you mean that.